# Replacing // with /* */ using sed command

Tags: sed, regular-expression

How do you replace // with /* */ in sed command?

I have tried:

```
sed -e "s/////* *//g" <<< filename
```

but this results in bad flag in substitute command: '/'

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you want to replace the string in *filename* itself, or in the file contents? With triple less than (`<<<`) you are doing the replacement on the filename, use single less than (`<`) for replacing the text inside the file.

Comment: Oh, this was meant to be in the file contents, so a single less should work. Also, thank you for your answer it works and I see where I was going wrong. However, I realized a fault in my question. I was supposed to change all comments in a file, which start with `//` to `/* */`  comments and replace the line so that it replaces from `//comments` to `/* comments */`. How would I approach this?

Comment: @ tpark; I added a solution for that in the edited answer.

Comment: As @user000001 points out, to change the comment style _safely_ would require something rather smarter than you describe. (For another example, if an existing comment already contains `*/`, then the rest of the line would get uncommented, changing the meaning of the code and probably giving an error on the `*/` you append.)

Answer (score 3):

In sed, you don't need to use `/` as a delimiter, any character will do. Use:

```bsh
sed 's://:/* */:g' < file
```

For the updated question, to replace inline comments `// comment` with block comments `/* comment */`, use the following:

```bsh
sed -E 's://(.*):/*\1*/:g' < file
```

The parenthesis defines a capture group, which is then referenced with `\1`.

This will only work for each line separately though, to merge consecutive comment lines you probably need a parser better than sed.

Note also that this will work for simple cases, but may fall for some inputs, consider what would happen for code like this:

```c
char *url = "https://example.com";
```

So check your files carefully after the conversion.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for the quick and concise answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo '// //' | sed 's@//@/* */@g'
/* */ /* */
```

Quoted from `man sed`:

> [2addr]s/regular expression/replacement/flags
>
> Substitute the replacement string for the first instance of the regular expression in the pattern space. **Any character other than backslash or newline can be used instead of a slash to delimit the RE and the replacement**. Within the RE and the replacement, the RE delimiter itself can be used as a literal character if it is preceded by a backslash.